# Host a WCF Service in a Windows Service but endpoint not found

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a dulpex WCF Service, which is hosted in a Windows Service. I installed the Windows Service from the command line via InstallUtil.exe, start the service from service management panel. Now it is the time to test WCF. So I add a new console project as a client, next step is to add web reference to the project.
However I got an error:

```
There was an error downloading `http://localhost:8733/KeyValueService/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata`.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8733
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: `http://localhost:8733/KeyValueService`.
```

The app.config in the service project has:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="VoiceApp.KeyValueService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/KeyValueService/" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="VoiceApp.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/KeyValueService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
</client>
```

I followed the configuration by [Metatata Exchange Endpoint Blog,](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/10/16/metadata-exchange-endpoint.aspx) but it would not help.

Also inside the windows service, we have:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(KeyValueService));
        serviceHost.Open();
        MyApplication.Start(); //  a long running code...
    }
```

**Updated:**

My step was creating a Windows service project, then added a WCF service.

Comment: Does service link accessible from browser? If not, try to disable firewall

Comment: Error: This page can't be displayed from IE.

Comment: The endpoint you have looks like IIS Express.  I have not created a duplex service before, but I have create a WCF service in a windows service host.  I would expect the endpoint to be tcp or named pipes.  Can you confirm that the windows service is not crashing when it starts?

Comment: @Adam47, Yes, it is not crashing when it starts. My endpoint is similar to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @Adam47 - A WCF Service that is hosted in a Windows service can use *any* WCF binding, even one of the http ones.  Just like a WCF service that is self-hosted.  http bindings are not limited to IIS only.

Comment: @Love - Check your event viewer.  It sounds like the account running the Windows service may not have the appropriate permissions to register the URI - if that is the case, you may see an error for that in the event viewer.

Comment: @Tim, nothing wrong in the event viewer. The windows firewall is turned off and the windows service does run. Maybe thee is something special for duplex WCF?

Comment: I think it's a Problem with the configuration. Try adding the endpoints in code (serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(...))

Comment: All, I updated the steps. Please notice: the WCF service is not in a separate project.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I've found that if you replace 'localhost' with the real IP address of the endpoint solves this issue.

Comment: Please don't post [identical answers](//stackoverflow.com/a/36651787) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*